# Cursor in SQL Server: Use loop / condition to find and replace a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a issue with my table in SQL Server. Sometime during a insert a normal value (20-50-80) changed by 1000000. It's really rare but to secure the average i need to make a fix before finding a new solution.

I want to take the value that exceeds 1000000 and replace them by the average of the value between it.

[This picture show the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwDe2.png)

I'm looking at the Cursor in SQL.

Here a exemple of my code. Some issue about the result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Avg_Kwh_TagValuesArchive]       
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @tagId INT
DECLARE @localTime DATE
DECLARE @tagValue FLOAT
DECLARE @limit FLOAT
DECLARE @temp FLOAT
DECLARE @tagValueBefore FLOAT
DECLARE @tagValueAfter FLOAT
SET @limit = 999999.9

DECLARE Cursor_FalseValues CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT TagID, LocalTime, TagValue 
    FROM TagValuesArchive
    ORDER BY LocalTime DESC

OPEN Cursor_FalseValues

FETCH Cursor_FalseValues
INTO @tagId, @localTime, @tagValue 

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

            IF (@tagValue>=@limit)
            BEGIN

                SET @tagValueBefore = 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 TagValue
                    FROM TagValuesArchive
                    WHERE LocalTime < @localTime
                    AND TagID = @tagID
                    AND TagValue IS NOT NULL
                    ORDER BY LocalTime DESC
                )

                SET @tagValueAfter = 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 TagValue
                    FROM TagValuesArchive
                    WHERE LocalTime > @localTime
                    AND TagID = @tagID
                    AND TagValue IS NOT NULL
                    ORDER BY LocalTime DESC
                )

                UPDATE dbo.TagValuesArchive
                SET TagValue= ((SUM( @tagValueBefore + @tagValueAfter ))/2)
                FROM dbo.TagValuesArchive
                WHERE LocalTime = @localTime
                AND TagID = @tagID

                FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_FalseValues
                INTO @tagId, @localTime, @tagValue 

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Fetch of the Cursos increment the line
                FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_FalseValues
                INTO @tagId, @localTime, @tagValue 
            END
    -- Fetch of the Cursos increment the line
    --FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_FalseValues
    --INTO @tagId, @localTime, @tagValue 
END

CLOSE Cursor_FalseValues
DEALLOCATE Cursor_FalseValues
END
```

I think my problem is a good example to use Cursor, but it's not very clear in my head.
I can take the wrong value and the values between it. But the Update in the database doesn't work.

I don't know if it's a cursor problem or a update. Maybe just a code syntax problem.

Thanks for any informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id int,
    val float
)


INSERT INTO @t (id, val)
VALUES
(1,.5),
(2,.7),
(3,.3),
(4,.74),
(5,.2341234),
(6,10000000),
(7,.9),
(8,.8),
(9,.87123),
(10,100000000),
(11,.99)
SELECT * FROM @t

DECLARE @limit FLOAT = 1000000;

;WITH OutOfOBoundsValues AS (
    SELECT id FROM @t WHERE val >= @limit
), Neighbourvalues AS (
    SELECT O.id, (t1.val+t2.val)/2 newval FROM OutOfOBoundsValues O
    JOIN @t t1 ON t1.id = O.id-1
    JOIN @t t2 ON t2.id = O.id+1

)
UPDATE @t 
SET val = N.newval
FROM @t t
JOIN Neighbourvalues N ON t.id = N.Id


SELECT * FROM @t
```

What happens here is that we select the data same as and above the limit.

Then we get the neighbouring values and calculates the mean value from them.

Lastly we update the out of bounds values with the mean value.

This should be much faster than your cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the information, a join is actually much faster for this example.